# Error while running Blink program

Tags: jvm, tinyos

I am working in TinyOs in Ubuntu 16.04. When I run the Blink program, the following error occurs:

```
[INFO] script
    2538 bytes in ROM
      56 bytes in RAM
[INFO] size (toolchain):
    text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   2596       2      56    2654     a5e build/telosb/main.exe
[INFO] generating symbol table
[INFO] generating listing
[INFO] creating ihex file
[INFO] writing TOS image
[INFO] writing TOS buildinfo
[INFO] running the wiring check
<JAVA_HOME>/lib/ext exists, extensions mechanism no longer supported; Use     
-classpath instead.
.Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
../../support/make/Makerules:362: recipe for target 'wiring_check' failed
make: *** [wiring_check] Error 1
```

Can anyone tell why this error occured?

Comment: `root@rsmjv-Studio-1555:/home/rsmjv# java -version
    <JAVA_HOME>/lib/ext exists, extensions mechanism no longer supported; Use -classpath instead.
    .Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
    Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`

Comment: I don't know Java. So not able to understand. Need help.

Answer (score 0):

TinyOS is trying to access features deprecated in Java 9. Try installing an earlier version of JRE, point JAVA_HOME to it